# Rebuild an array of integers after summing the digits of each element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have an strictly increasing array of length `n` ( 1 < n < 500) . We sum the digits of each element to create a new array with each elements values is in range 1 to 500.The task is to rebuild the old array from the new one. since there might be more than one answer, we want the answers with the minimum value of the last element.
Example:

> 3 11 23 37 45 123 =>3 2 5 10 9 6

now from the second array, we can rebuild the original array in many different ways for instance:

> 12 20 23 37 54 60

from all the possible combinations, we need the one we minimum last element.

**My Thoughts so far:**

The brute force way is to find all possible permutations to create each number and then create all combinations possible of all numbers of the second array and find the combination with minimum last element. It is obvious that this is not a good choice.

Using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-points-that-can-compose-a-given-number/?ref=rp) algorithm(with exponential time!) we can create all possible permutations of digits that sum to a number in the second arrays. Note that we know the original elements were less than 500 so we can limit the death of search of the algorithm.

One way I thought of that might find the answer faster is to:

1. start from the last element in the new arrays and find all possible
   numbers that their digit sum resulted this element.
2. Then try to use the smallest amount in the last step for this element.
3. Now try to do the same with the second to last element. If the
   minimum permutation value found for the second to last element is bigger
   than the one found for the last element, backtrack to the last
   element and try a larger permutation.
4. Do this until you get to the first element.

I think this is a greed solution but I'm not very sure about the time complexity. Also I want to know is there a better solution for this problem? like using `dp`?

Comment: I think you can do it in `O(n ^ 3)` with dynamic programming

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov can you explain more?

Comment: I'm curious as to the application of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's have our sequence `1`-based and the input sequence is called `x`.

We will also use an utility function, which returns the sum of the digits of a given number:

```
int sum(int x) {
  int result = 0;
  while (x > 0) {
    result += x % 10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Let's assume that we are at index `idx` and try to set there some number called `value` (given that the sum of digits of `value` is `x[idx]`). If we do so, then what could we say about the previous number in the sequence? It should be strictly less than `value`.

So we already have a state for a potential `dp` approach - `[idx, value]`, where `idx` is the index where we are currently at and `value` denotes the value we are trying to set on this index.

If the `dp` table holds `boolean` values, we will know we have found an answer if we have found a suitable number for the first number in the sequence. Therefore, if there is a *path* starting from the last row in the `dp` table and ends at row `0` then we'll know we have found an answer and we could then simply restore it.

Our recurrence function will be something like this:

```
f(idx, value) = OR {dp[idx - 1][value'], where sumOfDigits(value) = x[idx] and value' < value}
f(0, *) = true
```

Also, in order to restore the answer, we need to track the path. Once we set any `dp[idx][value]` cell to be true, then we can safe the `value'` to which we would like to *jump* in the previous table row.

Now let's code that one. I hope the code is self-explanatory:

```
boolean[][] dp = new boolean[n + 1][501];
int[][] prev = new int[n + 1][501];
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
  dp[0][i] = true;
}
for (int idx = 1; idx <= n; idx++) {
  for (int value = 1; value <= 500; value++) {
    if (sum(value) == x[idx]) {
      for (int smaller = 0; smaller < value; smaller++) {
        dp[idx][value] |= dp[idx - 1][smaller];
        if (dp[idx][value]) {
          prev[idx][value] = smaller;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `prev` table only keeps information about which is the **smallest** `value'`, which we can use as previous to our `idx` in the resulting sequence.

Now, in order to restore the sequence, we can start from the last element. We would like it to be minimal, so we can find the first one that has `dp[n][value] = true`. Once we have such element, we then use the `prev` table to track down the values up to the first one:

```
int[] result = new int[n];
int idx = n - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
  if (dp[n][i]) {
    int row = n, col = i;
    while (row > 0) {
      result[idx--] = col;
      col = prev[row][col];
      row--;
    }
    break;
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  out.print(result[i]);
  out.print(' ');
}
```

If we apply this on an input sequence:

```
3 2 5 10 9 6
```

we get

```
3 11 14 19 27 33
```

The time complexity is `O(n * m * m)`, where `n` is the number of elements we have and `m` is the maximum possible value that an element could hold.

The space complexity is `O(n * m)` as this is dominated by the size of the `dp` and `prev` tables.

Comment: Thanks but I think there is a problem. the thing is that each value in the new arrays is maximum 500. These means the original array can have very big numbers.

Comment: @FrastoFresto: Wow, that's a big difference!

Comment: @FrastoFresto, in order to obtain values in the range `[1,500]`, then the input array should hold values not more than `22` (as `sumOfDigits(499) = 22` and that's the maximum we can get as a sum of digits for numbers in the range `[1,500]`). Therefore, if your input array contains bigger values, then there is no way to obtain values in the range `[1,500]`

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov ok, what if the input array hold digits as big as 500? how does the algorithm chang?

Comment: @FrastoFresto, I will think about it and will further post a comment.

Comment: @FrastoFresto, if the input array holds values as big as `500`, then the shortest number we can construct would consist of around 56 digits. That overflows 64-bit types. I don't think there is an easy approach to such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a greedy algorithm: proceed through the array in order, setting each element to the least value that is greater than the previous element and has digits with the appropriate sum. (We can just iterate over the possible values and check the sums of their digits.) There's no need to consider any greater value than that, because increasing a given element will never make it possible to decrease a later element. So we don't need dynamic programming here.

We can calculate the sum of the digits of an integer *m* in O(log *m*) time, so the whole solution takes O(*b* log *b*) time, where *b* is the upper bound (500 in your example).

Comment: I don't understand your complexity evalution. I understood that 500 is the max value obtained after summing the digits, not the maximum value in the final array. I may miss something. I agree with the greedy approach.

Comment: @Damien: The question has been edited; at the time that I wrote this answer, it specified that 500 was the maximum value *before* summing the digits. I haven't had a chance yet to change the answer accordingly. (The "just iterate over the possible values" part is no longer reasonable.)